# C# - Убрать разрывы между строками в RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

В программе есть часть кода:

```
richTextBox.Document = new FlowDocument();
Paragraph par = new Paragraph();
par.Inlines.Add("smth1");
par.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
richTextBox.Document.Blocks.Add(par);
par = new Paragraph();
par.Inlines.Add("smth2");
richTextBox.Document.Blocks.Add(par);
```

Как сделать так, чтобы она выводила в RichTextBox то же самое, но без разрыва между строками ?

Comment: Как вариант, написать парсер.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тебе нужно почитать про типы добавляемых элементов в FlowDocument. Параграф для того и служит, чтобы разделять абзацы, в нем есть параметры, которые очень просто меняются (Margin и другие). Но в сути дела есть полезная штука Span, которая отделяет форматирование и может содержать сколько угодно вложенных элементов (кроме блочных). Совет: используй Span вместо Paragraph и посмотри, что такое LineBreak. Для изучения вопроса также полезно пробовать писать прямо в Дизайнере формы приблизительно то, что ты хочешь получить, эксперементируя со свойствами. Потом уже переходить на динамическое создание документа (так как оно требует четкого понимания тех действий, которые тебе нужны). Удачи!

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае достаточно задать свойство LineHeight.

```
Paragraph par = new Paragraph();
par.LineHeight = 1.0;
par.Inlines.Add("smth1");
par.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
richTextBox.Document.Blocks.Add(par);

par = new Paragraph();
par.LineHeight = 1.0;
par.Inlines.Add("smth2");
richTextBox.Document.Blocks.Add(par);
```

Или:

```
<RichTextBox Name="richTextBox" Block.LineHeight="1"/>
```